# The installer failed to create partition on disk. (Manjaro KDE Linux)

Tags: install, kde, manjaro

Решил поставить Manjaro KDE 20.1. Загрузился через UEFI и начал установку. Перешёл сразу в режим ручного раздела дисков.
У меня уже было место под расширенный том, внутри которого я буду досоздавать разделы. Сначала создал расширенный том, затем создал разделы: FAT32 с меткой boot, размером 500MiB и точкой монтирования /boot; linuxswap с меткой swap и размером 8000MiB; ext4 с оставшимся размером (40 GiB) и точкой монтирования /.

Спустя некоторое время после нажатия "установить" выскакивает окно со следующей ошибкой:

```
The installer failed to create partition on disk 'ST1000DM003-1ER162'.

========================================================================================== 

Create a new partition (48.83 GiB, extended) on ‘/dev/sda’ 

==========================================================================================
========================================================================================== 

Job: Create new partition on device ‘/dev/sda’ 

========================================================================================== 
========================================================================================== 

Command: sfdisk --force --append /dev/sda 

========================================================================================== 

Failed to add partition ‘New Partition’ to device ‘/dev/sda’. 
Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ... OK Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors Disk model: 
ST1000DM003-1ER1 Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes Disklabel type: dos Disk identifier: 0x948d652c Old situation: 
Device Boot Start End Sectors Size Id Type /dev/sda1 2048 206847 204800 100M 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT /dev/sda2 206848 307199490 306992643 146.4G 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT /dev/sda3 307200000 1851119615 1543919616 736.2G 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT /dev/sda4: No free sectors available. 
Failed to add #4 partition: No space left on device Leaving. Failed to add partition ‘New Partition’ to device ‘/dev/sda’.
```

И я понятия не имею, как решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Хочу рядом с виндой поставить. У меня та же ошибка, только на legacy(не uefi) и на manjaro 20.1 XFCE...
На виртуальную vmware ставяться все манжары, при выборе "Стереть диск".
Кучу способов перепробовал поставить на комп.
Слышал manjaro live-cd работает.
Как вариант, по идее, если его корректно всё настроить, то можно будет запускать со своего HDD - и получиться примерно таже установленная манжаро, если не хочешь "стирать весь диск". Попробую на досуге.
Среди дополнительной информации - попытка установить Линукс Минт последний - туже ошибку выдает, но ранее получалось установить Убунту и Кали. Не знаю откуда эта ошибка возникла.
Пробовал заранее создать ext4 раздел. В этом случае ошибку не выдает, после нажатия на "установить" в первом такте "монтирования точек ..(чего-то там))"(тире, касательно этих разделов).
Если при установке запускать - Gparted тоже ошибка эта видна, что не работает функция добавления разделов.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, я не знаю, в чём именно оказалась проблема. Скорее всего в испорченных сегментах диска.

Следующим утром у меня появился интернет, я сразу скачал GParted. В нём проверил все диски на наличие ошибок и самостоятельно в нём же разметил swap-файл (на 8 гб), boot (на 500 мб)  и всё остальное под файлы.
В программе установки выбрал самостоятельную разметку диска и файлопомойку пометил как '/' раздел. Далее просто начал установку, которая благополучно завершилась.

Однако, я до сих пор не знаю, в чём была проблема...